# How to install node-sass/gulp-sass on Ubuntu 14.04+ or Linux Mint 17+?

Tags: compiling, nodejs

I'm trying to switch from `gulp-ruby-sass` to `node-sass` which is based on `libsass` a C implementation faster than the classic Ruby version.

So far I've install the node packages:

### Node package

```bsh
cd /path/to/project
npm install --save-dev node-sass gulp-sass
```

### Gulpfile

I replaced the requirement as follow:

```
//sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
```

### Libsass

Then I went to lo for a `libsass` package, but [none is available currently](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/757).

So I wonder if anyone as a bash script to build it as [current instructions are unclear](https://github.com/sass/libsass/wiki/Building-with-autotools) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I documented my research as a [bash script as a gist](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/503d40a5c1a49cf8ae87) based on the [official doc](https://github.com/sass/libsass/wiki/Building-with-autotools)

### Compiling and Installing `libsass` and `sassc`

#### Install dependencies

```bsh
apt-get install automake libtool
```

#### Fetch sources

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git
git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc.git libsass/sassc
```

#### Create configure script

```bsh
cd libsass
autoreconf --force --install
cd ..
```

#### Create custom makefiles for **shared library**

For more info read: [Difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2649334/802365) before installing `libsass`.

```
cd libsass
autoreconf --force --install
./configure \
  --disable-tests \
  --enable-shared \
  --prefix=/usr 
cd ..
```

#### Build the library

```bsh
make -C libsass -j5
```

#### Install the library

```bsh
sudo make -C libsass -j5 install
```

### Testing

#### Only `node-sass`

```bsh
time node-sass /path/to/main.scss
```

Succeed with

```
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /mnt/data/projects/EVRPA/evrpa/web/main.css
node-sass ../web/styles/main.scss  0.42s user 0.03s system 95% cpu 0.471 total
```

#### `Gulp` with `ruby-sass`

```bsh
[17:48:21] Using gulpfile /mnt/data/projects/EVRPA/evrpa/web/gulpfile.js
[17:48:21] Starting 'css'...
[17:48:21] gulp-ruby-sass: directory
[17:48:23] gulp-ruby-sass: overwrite main.css
[17:48:24] Finished 'css' after 2.9 s
gulp css  4.60s user 0.35s system 46% cpu 10.605 total
```

#### `Gulp` with `node-sass`

```bsh
time gulp css
[17:47:59] Using gulpfile /mnt/data/projects/EVRPA/evrpa/web/gulpfile.js
[17:47:59] Starting 'css'...
[17:48:00] Finished 'css' after 1.1 s
gulp css  2.99s user 0.20s system 100% cpu 3.164 total
```

### Conclusion

My tests are no benchmark and have little value but `node-sass` seems to be **3-5x faster** than `ruby-sass`.

Comment: this doesn't work for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh the answer is pretty old and Ubuntu had a lot of release since. So, that's expected

Answer (score 4):

The above is not working anymore with the Ubuntu 18.04

I ended up with the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git ~/libsass
echo "export SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=~/libsass" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc.git ~/sassc
cd ~/sassc
make
echo "export PATH=$PATH:~/sassc/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sassc -v
```

Based on https://github.com/sass/sassc/blob/master/docs/building/unix-instructions.md

Comment: Can you elaborate on "current version"? Are you talking about `libsass`, `sassc`, Linux Mint, etc.? Please provide the version you used if possible.

Comment: this answer doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04.