# How to install libsass on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, makefile

I've been trying to install libsass on my dev machine to use `sassc`, but I'm not having any success. Most of the tutorials that I have found are from earlier this year and don't seem to work (for me) (e.g [install libsass ubuntu](http://crocodillon.com/blog/how-to-install-sassc-and-libsass-on-ubuntu)[ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566675/how-to-install-node-sass-gulp-sass-on-ubuntu-14-04-or-linux-mint-17)
This issue for me seems to be running the make file from the sassc directory.

```
nizzok@nizzok-ThinkPad-X201:~/sassc$ make
make BUILD="static" -C /home/nizzok/libsass
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nizzok/libsass'
mkdir lib
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘lib’: Permission denied
Makefile:227: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make[1]: *** [lib] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nizzok/libsass'
Makefile:212: recipe for target 'libsass-static' failed
make: *** [libsass-static] Error 2
nizzok@nizzok-ThinkPad-X201:~/sassc$ sudo make
make BUILD="static" -C /home/nizzok
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nizzok'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nizzok'
Makefile:212: recipe for target 'libsass-static' failed
make: *** [libsass-static] Error 2
```

So, are there more to date instructions? or any idea what's causing these errors?

Answer (score 5):

I too was trying to find `sassc` in Ubuntu 16.04 to build the [adapta theme](https://github.com/adapta-project/adapta-gtk-theme) but I couldn't. It seems that package is [available for Ubuntu 16.10 or greater](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sassc), but [not for 16.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/sassc).

So, what can you do? While I was searching, I found [blog post](http://crocodillon.com/blog/how-to-install-sassc-and-libsass-on-ubuntu) which shows the path, but it didn't work as instructed on that post.

I'm describing the steps I followed here.

### Step 1: Clone `libsass`, `sassc`, `sass-spec` repositories

I'm installing those library for all users. So, I choose, `/usr/local/lib` directory.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/
sudo git clone https://github.com/sass/sassc.git --branch 3.4.2 --depth 1
sudo git clone https://github.com/sass/libsass.git --branch 3.4-stable --depth 1
sudo git clone https://github.com/sass/sass-spec.git --depth=1
```

You need to use `sudo` because `/usr/local/lib` directory is root writable only.

### Step 2: Set the environment variable

I don't know if this step was necessary, but I did it eventually. The blog post's instruction will give error if you were not using a root shell.

```
echo 'SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

This sets the `SASS_LIBSASS_PATH` env variable which will be used while compiling `sassc` to find the required libraries.

source the changed file

```
source /etc/environment
```

### Step 3: Build `libsass`

You need to first build the `libsass` libraries. While you're in the `/usr/local/lib` directory use this command to build it

```
sudo make -C libsass
```

### Step 4: Build and install `sassc`

After step 3 is finished, while still on the `/usr/local/lib` directory, use this command to build `sassc`.

```
sudo make -C sassc
```

This will generate `sassc` binary in `sassc/bin/` folder. Now use this command to make the binary available globally.

```
sudo make -C sassc install
```

That's it. Now from anywhere, try `sassc` command to see if it's recognized.

### Shortcut

When I finished building and started writing this answer, I found a PPA for `sassc` used by the adapta theme maker `tista`. And it was for 16.04 Xenial. Though the version is older `3.2.3`, it will do the job I think.

Here is the PPA link: [https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/build](https://launchpad.net/%7Etista/+archive/ubuntu/build)

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Have fun!

---

#### Useful links

1. sassc build instruction - https://github.com/sass/sassc/blob/master/docs/building/unix-instructions.md
2. Reported issue with libsass build instruction - https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1556

Comment: Note the sassc build instructions prescribe a different layout. I couldn't get `sassc` to compile with `make` until I used their layout with `sassc` and `sass-spec` cloned as subdirs into the `libsass` directory (e.g. `libsass/sassc`, `libsass/sass-spec`.