# How to install node-sass on Ubuntu 18.04, and How to succesfully compile .scss file to css?

Tags: nodejs, css, grunt

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566675/how-to-install-node-sass-gulp-sass-on-ubuntu-14-04-or-linux-mint-17?rq=1) answers but it didn't work.

I am trying to compile files in my  `scss` folder to regular `css` files but it's hanged in between.

I installed node-sass from npm and it gives error as

```
gd@gd10:~/Desktop/portfolio/portfolio$ sudo npm install -g node-sass
[sudo] password for gd:
/usr/local/bin/node-sass -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

> node-sass@4.9.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64 :{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:738:3)
    at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@10.6.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.15rc1\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.6.0
gyp verb command install [ '10.6.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "10.6.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 10.6.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.6.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gd/.npm/_logs/2018-08-05T16_10_00_943Z-debug.log
gd@gd10:~/Desktop/portfolio/portfolio$
```

Answer (score 13):

I finally found a solution

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

I hope this will help many of us.
Must update this answer since node-sass is now mostly deprecated, use npm sass module instead
"npm i sass" or "yarn add sass" and works like a charm on all ubuntu OS-es.Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I used `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm gulp-sass` to install gulp-sass